# Use custom jQuery plugin for Angular Directive with Webpack

Tags: jquery, angularjs, plugins, webpack, require

I am trying to require a custom jquery plugin for use on a directive's element with Webpack. I began implementing in the way I expected it to work.

```
// example.directive.js

var customJQPlugin = require('./customJQPlugin.plugin');

...

  link: function (scope, elem) {
    angular.element(elem).customJQPlugin({
      some: 'options'
    });
  }

...
```

This would apply the plugin to the element.

and then the plugin file (in same directory as directive)

```
// customJQPlugin.plugin.js

(function ($) {

  $.fn.customJQPlugin = function (options) {
    var el = this;
    ...
  }

})(jQuery)
```

My question is, what is a typical way to do this, I currently have a few errors where `this` is undefined, and `customJQPlugin is not a function` when chained onto `angular.element(elem).customJQPlugin(options)`

This is more about how to structure the jQuery plugin file in a way that Webpack can `require` it in order to be applied to an angular directive. I'm sure that the IIFE is not needed for this, but am unsure of how to refactor for Webpack.

**EDIT:** asume jQuery and $ is globally available

Comment: you should use, elem.customPlugin, as angular.element(elem) is wrong selector.

Comment: Unfortunately I'd tried this, the outcome was the same for both.

Comment: $(elem).customPlugin(). I am not sure. just try.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to get it working, but I am unsure if it is the best way.

```
// customJQPlugin.plugin.js

module.exports = function (options) { ... }
```

Then in my directive file I can do the following:

```
$.fn.customJQPlugin = require('./customJQPlugin.plugin');

...

link: function() {
  $(elem).customJQPlugin({
    some: 'options'
  });
}

....
```

I still have a few errors but this looks more likely to be unrelated to the question.

It's not the cleanest but it does work, will update if I find out more.

Comment: This is what I mentioned in comment.

Comment: It was certainly correct, but the query was surrounding how to export and require the plugin into the directive. How to apply it to the element was a side point, though valid :)